# have to tap twice to enable clicking the buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

In my android app every time i start the app i have to tap on buttons/screen twice to get it clicked. this means after loading the app i have to tap anywhere on the screen and then click the buttons in order fire the click events. after first tap everything works fine all the buttons are working. i need to know how to get rid of this double tap on start because it makes user uncomfortable . i searched in google but nothing found. let me know if you need parts of code. i didn't put it here because i don't know what part i have to put here :)

edit: here is my xml code for button. hope nothing wrong here (i guess)

```html
    <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Vignette"
                            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                            android:layout_width="80dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@drawable/btnstatus"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:paddingTop="1dp"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/vignette"
                            android:text="Vignette"
                            android:textAllCaps="false"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and from my mainactivity oncreateview

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String image_path= intent.getStringExtra("Imagepath");

    fileUri = Uri.parse(image_path);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    mainview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
```

and this is where my mainview get enabled

```
 void enablemainlayout()
{
    ((CropImageView)findViewById(R.id.cropImageView)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imgviewmain.setImageBitmap(mainimage);
    imgviewmain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



    mainview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    colorview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    brightnessview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    contrastview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    saturateview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    vignetteview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    coloroverlayview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    blurview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cropview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}
```

little explanation: mainview is layout view that contains the buttons that i want to press in main activity. in addition i have action bar that also needs double tap on screen to fire click events .

link to my full xml file for main layout
[link to xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l28o7p0qe7fhxqq/xml.docx?dl=0)

and button onclicklistner

```
    cropping.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            enableonlycroplayout();

       //     cropview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (mainview.getVisibility() == View.GONE && cropview.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {


                android.support.v4.app.Fragment myfragment = new Fragment_For_Crop();

                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fmcrop = getSupportFragmentManager();

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(myfragment, "fragment_for_crop").commit();


            }


        }
    });
```

this just one button in main layout. thanks

Comment: can you please provide the elevant part of your code? If you need to double click, then I guess there is a focus problem. The view gets touched by click hasn´t the focus. The first touch gives the focus, that´s why you need to click twice. The second touch then is recogized as the click event.

Comment: thanks and added some explanation. let me know if i need to explain this more.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs so i need to know how to solve this focus issue then :)

Comment: Is this the compete layout? I guess not because you are talking about buttons. It´s important to see the complete layout. Another possible issue could be your onClick implementation. So please also, post the onClick method.

Comment: @Opiatefuchsadded

Comment: no one?  :( ....

Comment: you have set a style for your buttons, even here could be the issue. Please post this style. Is that the click method for all buttons?

Comment: ya that is the click method. and i am not getting what u mean by  "Style". isn't it the xml part for button? i am also learning android. so just pardon me

Comment: so every button is set to this onClickMethod? Or what is `cropping` ? What happens inside your `enableonlycroplayout();` method? The button style is set via `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"` in your layout xml. But forget about this, it´s a android specific style, I just haven´t seen it....

Comment: what you mean by every button is set to this onclickmethod? for every button i use onclickmethod with different functions and the posted one is only for  button named as "cropping". and i have several layout on above each other. in enablecroplayout i do setvisible layout for crop function enable and others disable. but after at start i perform enablemainlayout which this double tap scenario occurs. i just set the visibility of main view  at the start. like....  
    
        mainview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: the reason I asked this is because there could be some issue in your onClickMethod. And if yes, there must be some comon ground that all views have. No matter, I guess it´s related to your xml layouts HorizontalView, where your buttons are inside. Try the following: set for **every Button** in your layout the attribute: `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`, deinstall your app, clean your project and reinstall. Then try if it works...

Comment: tried as you said still same problem exists .. but if it is related to horizontalscroll view then why this double tap issue comes to my action bar items too? they also needed double tap for first time like the mainview buttons ..

Comment: This was only an assumption. If it´s not a problem, can you proivide your project for me? Sharing it via dropbox or something....? I guess it´s too much here to post...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs  hi thanks for trying to help. just found myself an answer.posted below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi after working for hours to find a solution for this problem i found an answer. the problem caused by

```
 View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
 int uiOptions = 0;
 uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION ;
 decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

i used those lines at  the beginning of oncreate to hide navigation bar from the screen. To solve the problem i just changed above lines as follows

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = 0;
uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

i don't know how this solved the problem i just changed it and it Worked. but i hope this will be helpful to anyone who get the same trouble. Thanks and have a nice day....

Comment: Thanks for finding and posting the solution! I had the similar problem and used your solution and it worked.